# Unknown issue while rotating bones

Tags: c++, transformation, blender, glm-math, skeletal-mesh

I faced a strange behaviour while was making a test skeleton rotation, here come the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bones.size(); ++i) {
    u2long parentlink = bones[i].blenderBone.parent;
    bone* b = &bones[i];
    
    if (!parentlink) {
        b->parent = nullptr;
        b->parentName = "no parent";

        glm::mat4 tailtrans = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), b->local_tail);
        glm::mat4 headtrans = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), b->local_head);

        b->tailmatrix = tailtrans * b->bonematrix;
        b->headmatrix = headtrans * b->bonematrix;

        b->renderedmatrix = b->headmatrix;

    }
    else {
        std::optional<bone> bpar = loader->getBone(parentlink);
        std::string parname = bpar->name;
        bones[i].parent = getBone(parname);
        bones[i].parentName = parname;

        glm::mat4 tailtrans = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), b->local_tail);
        glm::mat4 headtrans = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), b->local_head);

        b->headmatrix = b->parent->tailmatrix * headtrans * b->bonematrix;
        b->tailmatrix = b->parent->tailmatrix * tailtrans * b->bonematrix;

        b->renderedmatrix = b->headmatrix;
    };
};
```

**local_tail** is bone bindspose start at bone space,
**local_tail** is bone bindpose end at bone space,
**bonematrix** is bone bindpose rotation,
**headmatrix** is used for rendering the bones and is matching bindpose model-space matrix for any bone,
**tailmatrix** for further transformations

And that gives me result which I find correct:
[bindpose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOMHr.png)

however, if I add a random bone rotation before the cycle:

```
glm::mat4 r = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), 0.89f, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
bones[8].bonematrix = bones[8].bonematrix * r;
```

the rendering is done strange:
[Wrong, spine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2QmI.png)

the following bone above **the rotated one** is rendered at its bindpose position, BUT the rest of the bones above are stacking all positions and rotations offsets correctly, which is the reason I post the question. The issue applies to any other bone connected to its parent:
[Wrong, right arm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yhcA.png)

But rotating root bone brings correct result this time:
[Correct, root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQJcr.png)

I find this line:

```
b->tailmatrix = b->parent->tailmatrix * tailtrans * b->bonematrix;
```

quite suspicious, after having thought all over it seems to me this one:

```
b->tailmatrix = b->parent->tailmatrix * b->bonematrix * tailtrans;
```

or better this:

```
b->tailmatrix = b->headmatrix * tailtrans;
```

should bring correct results, but swaping to these lines brings chaos, bindpose is a mess, the same mess applies to any bone (except root one) rotation:
[Bindpose, wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3q46.png)

Where am I wrong with that code? I bashed this wall for three weeks but when ist almost through my front is almost dead as well :/

(this is blender file parser, the bones not matching the model is a temporary issue with blender "magical" transform axis, all bones above the torso are parented down)

Answer (score 0):

All right, got it done, the line:

```
b->tailmatrix = b->parent->tailmatrix * tailtrans * b->bonematrix;
```

I made this line while I was, errmm...guessing, and it managed to give results but now I have understood why it did, in Blender model offset to head and tail of the next bone is done in parent bone's TAIL local space for both of tail and head, but I thought it was different. The next and the last thing to add - apply rotation offset right into this line, for the bone head matrix has rotated offset but unrotated position (armature[3], bindpose, in my case) and tail matrix  receives rotated offset as well as updated position:

```
b->tailmatrix = b->parent->tailmatrix * tailtrans * (b->bonematrix * b->localrot);
```

**b->localrot** is rotation offset matrix.

so the code for now looks this way, and the test rotation is done fine:

```
bones[8].localrot = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), 1.0f, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

for (int i = 0; i < bones.size(); ++i) {
    bone* b = &bones[i];

    if (!b->parent) {
        glm::mat4 tailtrans = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), b->local_tail);
        glm::mat4 headtrans = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), b->local_head);

        b->headmatrix = b->bonematrix * b->localrot * headtrans;
        b->tailmatrix = b->bonematrix * b->localrot * tailtrans;

        b->renderedmatrix = b->headmatrix;

    }
    else {
        glm::mat4 tailtrans = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), b->local_tail);
        glm::mat4 headtrans = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), b->local_head);

        b->headmatrix = b->parent->tailmatrix * headtrans * b->bonematrix;
        b->tailmatrix = b->parent->tailmatrix * tailtrans * (b->bonematrix * b->localrot);

        b->renderedmatrix = b->headmatrix;
    };
};
```

[all good.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOx7o.png)